# How to make a branch as master w/o using git merge?

Tags: git

**Branches**

- master
- staging ~*contains latest version*

**Current setup**

```
+-master-+-master--+-master--+
         +-staging-+-staging-+-staging-+-staging-+
```

**Make staging as master**

What I want to do now is to make `staging` as the `master` without using `git merge` because I am no longer able to keep track of the changes and the position of the heads.

Current branch is **staging** and I wanted to achieve this

```
+-master-+-master--+-master--+                   +-master-+
         +-staging-+-staging-+-staging-+-staging-+
```

Can the master be overridden by staging using these steps?

1. `git checkout master`
2. *change something*
3. `git add *`
4. `git commit -m "override the master version"`
5. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard staging
```

This will make `master` point to the same commit as `staging`. If your `master` has any commits that are not in `staging` you will lose them.

Comment: yes Paul, any commits in `master` that are not in `staging` are all good for discard

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
git checkout staging
# keep the content of this branch, but record a merge
git merge --strategy = ours master   
git checkout master
git merge staging             # fast-forward master up to the merge
```

If you want your history to be a little clearer, I'd recommend adding some information to the merge commit message to make it clear what you've done. Change the second line to:

```
git merge --strategy=ours --no-commit master
git commit          # add information to the template merge message
```

Comment: OP said he does not want merges because he lost track of his changes... he wants to throw `master` away.

Comment: This does make the history of master exactly the same as the history of staging, doesn't it? In that sense, master is completely thrown away. Basically the only difference compared to Paul's answer is that a new merge-commit is created, in which both of the branches now point. Or am I wrong? We used this method in one project, and it worked pretty well for us.

Comment: It may give you the same end result in regards to the files in the final commit, but from the point of view of the commit graph, it does _not_ do the same. The OP wants to "Make staging as master", which translates (for me) to "let the `master` branch point at the commit of the `staging` branch", not to "have a new commit with two parents, one of which was ignored during the merge operation, but only where conflicts happened". Foremost, the new commit _will_ contain changes of the old master that the OP explicitely wants to throw away (`--strategy ours` only overrides conflicts).